# CefSharp.WPF won't run as a self-contained file .NET Core

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, cefsharp

I was able to create and run a browser in a WPF window using CefSharp (84.4.10.0). Everything runs fine in debug/release mode. If I try to publish as a self-contained win-x64 executable. The app crashes with the following exception:

```
Application: App.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.700.20.47201
.NET Core Version: 3.1.9
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The invocation of the constructor on type 'CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CefSharp.Cef' threw an exception.
---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
at CefSharp.Cef..cctor()

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at CefSharp.Cef.get_IsInitialized()
at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.NoInliningConstructor()
at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser..ctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
at RssFeedTicker.RssFeedWindow.InitializeComponent()
at RssFeedTicker.MainWindow.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at App.App.Main()
```

I've also copied these files to the same directory as the output file:

```
cef.pak
CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll
CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
CefSharp.Core.dll
CefSharp.dll
CefSharp.WinForms.dll
cef_100_percent.pak
cef_200_percent.pak
cef_extensions.pak
d3dcompiler_43.dll
d3dcompiler_47.dll
devtools_resources.pak
HAP.dll
icudtl.dat
libcef.dll
libEGL.dll
libGLESv2.dll
loc.txt
natives_blob.bin
snapshot_blob.bin
widevinecdmadapter.dll
```

The app does not run as a self-contained exe.

Comment: What version of CefSharp? What command did you use to publish? I'd suggest adding some additional tags. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ for helpful check list

Comment: Version="84.4.10"
I just used the publish command within visual studio. I published to folder, self-contained,win-x64, produce single file, enable ReadyToRun compilation, and trim unused assemblies.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't notice before but the CefSharp library is all .NET Framework 4.5.2. I can see that is obviously not being added to the single file exe that's being produced, but I would assume the dependencies on it would still load and work. I guess not?

Comment: Try building from command line as per https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample#net-core-support

Comment: I have other reports it works, so likely some option you've chosen, I believe trimming assemblies can be problematic.

Comment: Super @amaitland! I think you found it, I did not see that article before and I did a quick test and it seems to be working ok now! thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Instructions building CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample#net-core-support)

The above link had the instructions needed to publish correctly:

When publishing a self-contained app using a runtime identifier win-x64 or win-x86, you need to set the Platform property to x64 or x86; as otherwise it would be AnyCPU and the check in the .targets file of the NuGet package would fail.

Example:

```
x86: dotnet publish -f netcoreapp3.0 -r win-x86 -p:Platform=x86
x64: dotnet publish -f netcoreapp3.0 -r win-x64 -p:Platform=x64
```

It is possible to publish the application as single EXE file by adding -`p:PublishSingleFile=true`.